# how can I simulate a json file input for a jest test?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have this function to write a unit test, I have a .json file on the same folder to be passed as a parameter but how can I pass it as a parameter?

```
export const getColumnsFromJsonFile = async (file) => {
  if (file?.type === 'application/json') {
    const result = await new window.Response(file).json()
    return Object.keys(result)
  }
}
```

`./test.json` is just text, what I have to do to transform in a readable file by `Response`?

`expect(await getColumnsFromJsonFile('./test.json')).toEqual([...])`